# Is SecurityContextHolder thread safe?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I use `SecurityContextHolder` and a custom `UserDetailsService` to obtain `UserDetails` from `SecurityContextHolder`:

```
Object o = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
UserDetailsDTO user = (UserDetailsDTO) o;
```

I left out the null checks, etc., but that's the idea.  I'm using this in an `@Around` pointcut of an `@Aspect`:

```
@Around("execution(* user.service.*.*(..))")
public Object audit(ProceedingJoinPoint call) throws Throwable {
     // get user id
     // add audit row in db
}
```

Looking at the `SecurityContextHolder` class, it uses a `ThreadLocal` by default, but the pointcut stuff also seems to have some sort of encapsulated threading logic.

Is it possible that there could be user collision (i.e. access UserA from one session for a UserB audit event in another concurrent session), or possibly a null user altogether.

Is there a better way to obtain the credentials/user profile?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it's thread safe with the default strategy (`MODE_THREADLOCAL`) (as long as you don't try to change the strategy on the fly). However, if you want spawned threads to inherit `SecurityContext` of the parent thread, you should set `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL`.

Also aspects don't have any "threading logic", they are executed at the same thread as the adviced method.

Comment: I saw that, but man does that seem like a huge miscue for the Spring guys.  A static util class, and setStrategyName has this Javadoc blurb: `Do NOT call this method more than once for a given JVM, as it will reinitialize the strategy and adversely affect any existing threads using the old strategy.`  I think I'll probably end up creating a singleton wrapper class.

Comment: I guess there is also a system property:  `public static final String SYSTEM_PROPERTY = "spring.security.strategy";`

Answer (score 2):

in general, ThreadLocal will not be friendly in a global cached thread pool. 
An ExecutorService's default cached thread pool (Executors.newCachedThreadPool()) will have either the initializing thread's ThreadLocal storage, or an empty one. In this situation, setting MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL will not change anything, unless the cached threadpool is initialized per request, which would be a pretty bad usage of it..
Make sure any underlying frameworks or libraries are not using the Executors.newCachedThreadPool() to provide thread pooling for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is thread safe . You should just be calling
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()

Comment: All of a sudden I'm getting a nullpointer exception. It has always worked in many project that I have done.

Comment: Have you switched to Jdk 11?

Comment: No. I'm on JDK 16. Have always been using it. It maybe because I was calling it from a template's function, which is being called in a different thread. So, instead, I switched to `RequestContextHolder`, getting the servlet, then session and pulling the security context from there.